# Appveyor - Compiling static qt5.10 application (with openssl and qml webview)

Tags: qt, static, qt5, appveyor

I'm trying to set up autobuild appveyor on my Qt project.
My app is using qt5.10.1, with qml and openSSL features.

I'm lost... I didn't know from where to start :/

**# 1:**
I found some examples of .apveyor.yml config files, but they are all using mingw32 compilator which do not allow me to use qml webview module ([why](https://forum.qt.io/topic/50314/solved-qtwebengine-module-not-found-on-windows-chromium-does-not-work-with-mingw/11))... I didn't find what I have to write in my appveyor config file to compile my app with msv2017 where is the compilator ?

Actually, my appveyor.yml looks like that (I try to do as QtCreator is doing on my  local computer but it's not working)

```
image: Visual Studio 2017
branches:
  only:
    - master

install:
  - set QTDIR=C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2017_64
  - set PATH=%QTDIR%\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin;%PATH%;

build_script:
  - qmake app/QRegovar.pro -spec win32-msvc
  - qmake_all
  - C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release

deploy:
  - provider: GitHub
    artifact: C:/projects/qregovar
    draft: true
    prerelease: false
    on:
      branch: master
      appveyor_repo_tag: true
```

And it's failling with the following error:

```
Build started
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/REGOVAR/QRegovar.git C:\projects\qregovar
git checkout -qf 7357eb2adab349c4de9e0b346dc99027964ea5a5
Running Install scripts
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2017_64
set PATH=%QTDIR%\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin;%PATH%;
qmake app/QRegovar.pro -spec win32-msvc
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Output:
===================
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
Command exited with code 3
```

**# 2:** 
I'm also wondering if appveyor is using qt static build ? As I would like to create "ready to use" package for the user ?

Comment: Not a direct solution to your problem(s), but I have setup my own ci scripts for appveyor for dynamic and static builds over here: https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtModules/tree/master/ci/win and https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtModules/blob/master/qtcreator_wizards/module/appveyor.yml - may help you to see how it's done.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using CMake, but I guess the trick is to setup 'cl' compiler into PATH, so qmake is able to find it.

In sample appveyor scripts the main build script is '.\qtmodules-travis\ci\win\build.bat'. This script will check/use AppVeyor matrix-defined variable for platform (line 7+) and then the script define VC_DIR etc.

And on the end is invoking script referred by you 'build-msvc.bat' where is invoked:

```
call %VC_DIR% %VC_VARSALL% || exit /B 1
```

QtCreator will do the setup for you (you are using Kits...)

When you are building in clean command line, you should do 'vcvarsXXX.bat call yourself before 'qmake' call.

In my opinion AppVeyor doesn't trigger this call for you, because developer may wish different build env. setup (e.g. x86, x64, arm etc.). It's your choice. Actually this is the hint as well when you start 'Qt command line' on your PC from start menu (it call 'C:\Qt\5.11.0\msvc2017_64\bit\qtenv2.bat' shell setup script)